# Choose to create common functions or class private member functions

Tags: c++, function

Say I have a function named foo(), and a class A. For class A, it will use foo() for some purpose, but foo() won't use any attribute of class A.

In this case, shall I put foo() as a common function outside the class, or I just keep it as private functions of class A?

Do you have some reasoning rules for choosing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to make it a class member. Just define it as a function within class definition.

This is an excellent explanation how non-member functions are actually good thing and can make your code better: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401197

This is also a good reference: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Answer (score 0):

Depend of what foo method is for?. If any other class is using the method create it in a general class like utils or something similiar. If  foo() is just for class A use make it private in class A.

Comment: If `foo()` doesn't access the state of A class, there is no reason to make it member.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic true, but this would be a good use of `private static`

Comment: no it wouldn't. If it doesn't use any member of the class, why should it be a class member? It is an implementation detail, why spoil the class header with it?

Answer (score 0):

If foo() is called once by class A, I suggest to put it as a private member function of A.
Otherwise, foo() will be a Free Function if it locates at file scope. Free Function can be a threat to the global name space. It a free function is defined with internal linkage in a .h file or with external linkage in a .c file, it may collide with another function definition with the same name during program integration.

If foo() is used multiple times, putting foo() into a utility class/struct as a static function will be a good idea.